# How to re-use subworkflow in UML activity diagram

Tags: android-activity, uml, diagram

I'm trying to model a pipeline in UML as an activity diagram, and I'm not sure how to describe a process consisting of multiple steps, where the user can decide which parts to execute:

-case 1: only A
 -case 2: A and B
 -case 3: A, B and C (Note: B can not be skipped in order to process C)

But if I put it into an activity diagram, I have to draw each sub-workflow multiple times:
[image]

So I don't think I'm doing it right. Maybe someone could help me with it?

Comment: What's the medium guard (btw. brackets are missing)? "Maybe"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what I was looking for was a nested activity as shown in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331641/how-do-i-represent-nested-actions-in-a-uml-activity-diagram

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with your diagram:

1. You are missing the square brackets around the guard. So it should be `[Yes]`, `[No]`, etc.
2. The middle part of the decision has no guard, so the flow will take that way in any case.
3. The lower Activity has 3 incoming edges, but only one will have a token. So it will never continue. You need to merge the flows from above prior to it.

Basically you could leave the actions this way. I'd probably pull out `A` (oh, I see that bruno suggested the same) since it's performed in all cases. So your decision will be left with two outputs. Although from a "physical view" your decision is made first (the user has to interact) will be after `A` has already been performed, the output/consequences will be the same. So this is kind of a business decision.

Answer (score 1):

it is ok except that yes/no is not enough to separate three cases :-)

you can also move the test after A being executed in all case